# How to solve async search options delay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm creating a **debounced tag search form** which should fetch options and return `searchResults` to feed `loadOptions`.

**Issue**: because of the debounce, there is a consistent delay between the "correct" received options and the options displayed. The "correct options" are displayed on next call (one character minimum).

**Idea** (might not be the best): I would like to async/await `loadOptions()` and wait for `useSearchTags()` to return. Someone had the same issue there (https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3145#issuecomment-434286534) and shared a solution. My case is a bit different as I am not directly fetching in `loadOptions()`. Any idea?

### Codesandbox minimal example

https://codesandbox.io/s/debounce-react-select-loadoptions-tgud8?file=/src/App.js

### Captures

[image: On first character: no option displayed]
[image: On second character: options from first character response displayed]

### Code

```js
// helpers/useDebouncedSearch.js

import { useState } from 'react';
import AwesomeDebouncePromise from 'awesome-debounce-promise';
import { useAsync } from 'react-async-hook';
import useConstant from 'use-constant';
import to from 'await-to-js';


const useDebouncedSearch = (searchFunction) => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');

  const debouncedSearchFunction = useConstant(() =>
    AwesomeDebouncePromise(searchFunction, 300)
  );

  const searchResults = useAsync(
    async () => {
      if (inputText.length === 0) {
        return [];
      } else {
        let [err, debouncedResults] = await to(debouncedSearchFunction(inputText));
        if(err) return [];

        // reformat tags to match AsyncSelect config
        const refactorTags = (tags) => {
          return tags.map(tag => ({ label: tag.label, value: tag._id }))    
        }

        return (debouncedResults.length !== 0) ? 
          refactorTags(debouncedResults) : 
          [];
      }
    },
    [debouncedSearchFunction, inputText]
  );

  return {
    inputText,
    setInputText,
    searchResults
  };
}

export default useDebouncedSearch;
```

```js
// SearchTags.js

import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import api from '../blablalivre-api.js';
import useDebouncedSearch from '../helpers/useDebouncedSearch.js';
import AsyncCreatableSelect from 'react-select/async-creatable';

import './SearchTags.scss';

const fetchTags = async text => 
  (await api.searchTags(text));

const useSearchTags = () => useDebouncedSearch(text => fetchTags(text));

const SearchTagsRender = (props) => {
  const { inputText, setInputText, searchResults } = useSearchTags();

  const loadOptions = async (inputValue) => {
    console.log('searchResults.result: ', searchResults.result);
    return searchResults.result;
  }

  const handleOnChange = (tags) => {
    props.updateTagsSelections(tags);
  }

  // issue AsyncCreatableSelect: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3412

  return (
    <AsyncCreatableSelect
      isCreatable
      isMulti
      inputValue={inputText}
      onInputChange={setInputText}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      loadOptions={loadOptions}
      cacheOptions
      placeholder='Ajouter une thématique'
      isClearable={false}
      id='search-tags'
      classNamePrefix='search-tags'
      // to hide menu when input length === 0
      openMenuOnClick={false}
      // to remove dropdown icon
      components={{ DropdownIndicator:() => null, IndicatorSeparator:() => null }}
      // to custom display when tag is unknown
      formatCreateLabel={inputValue => `Ajouter "${inputValue}"`}
      // to reset focus after onChange = needs to user Refs
    />
  );
};

export default SearchTagsRender;
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how loadOptions is being implemented in your case. loadOptions needs to provide AsyncSelect with a promise which resolves when the values are available. However when you use `useAsync` to provide searchResults, it returns you a response with loading values initially and then a re-render causes it return the result when response are available

however, loadOptions in your case returns `searchResults.result` which during the time of loading state is `undefined`.

Now since the `loadOptions` is resolved with undefined values, on next re-render it does't use the value unless the input is changed

The solution here is not not use `useAsync` and provide `searchResults` as a loadOptions function

```
const SearchTagsRender = props => {
  const { inputText, setInputText, loaadSearchResults } = useSearchTags();

  console.log(loaadSearchResults);
  const handleOnChange = tags => {
    const tagsFromForm = tags || [];

    props.updateTagsFromForm(tagsFromForm);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <AsyncCreatableSelect
        isCreatable
        isMulti
        inputValue={inputText}
        onInputChange={setInputText}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        loadOptions={loaadSearchResults}
        cacheOptions
        placeholder="Ajouter une thématique"
        isClearable={false}
        id="search-tags"
        classNamePrefix="search-tags"
        // to hide menu when input length === 0
        openMenuOnClick={false}
        // to remove dropdown icon
        components={{
          DropdownIndicator: () => null,
          IndicatorSeparator: () => null
        }}
        // to custom display when tag is unknown
        formatCreateLabel={inputValue => inputValue}
        // to reset focus after onChange = needs to user Refs
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchTagsRender;
```

---

```
const useDebouncedSearch = searchFunction => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");

  const debouncedSearchFunction = useConstant(() =>
    AwesomeDebouncePromise(searchFunction, 300)
  );

  const loaadSearchResults = async () => {
    if (inputText.length === 0) {
      return [];
    } else {
      let [err, debouncedResults] = await to(
        debouncedSearchFunction(inputText)
      );
      if (err) return [];

      console.log("debouncedResults: ", debouncedResults);

      // reformat tags to match AsyncSelect config
      const refactorItems = items => {
        return items.map(item => ({
          label: item.name,
          value: item.alpha3Code
        }));
      };

      return debouncedResults.length !== 0
        ? refactorItems(debouncedResults)
        : [];
    }
  };

  return {
    inputText,
    setInputText,
    loaadSearchResults
  };
};
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/debounce-react-select-loadoptions-g8i0f?file=/src/helpers/useDebouncedSearch.js:213-1105)

Comment: Thanks Shubham for your detailled answer and solution! useAsync debounced the search input. How would you **implement a debounced search** in my case?

Comment: @Pierre We are still using debounce isn't it with `debouncedSearchFunction`

Comment: you're right! Thanks a lot for your help and time :)